# HERE SDK: Android PositioningManager.setDataSource(LocationDataSource) does not exist

Tags: android, here-api

I've followed the instructions for the tutorials for Android using HERE APIs.
PositioningManager.setDataSource(LocationDataSource) doesn't exist as described https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/advanced-positioning.html
The documentation needs to be updated or library import needs to be less confusing. I really do not know what's going on. How can I get positioning to work?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are using the Starter Version of SDK which does not have the DataSource feature ? I could see the setDataSource method is available in the HERE Premium SDK.

[image]

The setDataSource is intended if you want to provide any external GPS sources (other than mobile device's default) , simple positioning can be started just by calling PositioningManager.start(LocationMethod) (https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-positioning.html)

Comment: How can setDataSource provide external GPS? Nothing in the documentation suggests that one can provide external GPS. LocationDataSourceHERE is the only type setDataSource accepts.

Comment: You would need to create a new class which extendes LocationDataSource (https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/index.html) , override the methods of the class to provide location updates from your external GPS device and then provide an instance of your new class to PositioningManager.